# How to use carmen for country_select in formatstic

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, formtastic

How can I use carmen for country_select with formtastic? Right now I am using country_Select and it works fine but I need the iso codes now and it seems it is not provided by country_select.

Answer (score 0):

according to this thread:

https://groups.google.com/d/msg/formtastic/w11y24ARY9c/AyO5OknerXgJ

"The latest version on git now works fine with formtastic."

I just tried it, and it's working for my Rails 2.3 app, looks like it'll work just as well in Rails 3+